# Ошибка размера БД на Denwer

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, импорт

Всем привет!) У меня такая вот проблемка.. Ставлю на Denwer Базу данных на WordPress. Запилила я ее как нужно по правилам, и вот тут изначально выдало вот такую ошибку в PhpMyAdmin: 8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Update your post_max_size in php.ini to a larger value.

Зашла я в php.ini и поменяла в двух строках вот это

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept. ; http://php.net/post-max-size post_max_size = 1000M

и

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize upload_max_filesize = 1000M

и изменила оба значения на 1000М с 8 и 2. Но вот тут незадача. Когда снова загружаю импортом БД, выдает Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47237812 bytes) in Z:\home\localhost\www\Tools\phpmyadmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 290

Что я делаю не так? Помогите плиз..

Comment: используйте данные поменьше размером)) либо спецутилиты импорта

Comment: после того как я вставила ошибку в GoogleTranslate, я поняла что дело в том что у меня очень большой размер самой БД и что типа сам PhpMyAdmin не пропускает такие размеры БД. Вот я и подумала что нужно увеличить пропуск.. ХЗ уже что дальше сделать чтобы сама БД встала.

Comment: Оооо... оно каким-то чудом загрузило БД на PhpMyAdmin.. Но. Выдает вот такое https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ImwEyHwkaREytSTf9OxLSM4RNxT3rfxI

Comment: в Денвере есть консольная mysql, выполните импорт через нее и все

Comment: Основное "не так" - использование денвера (равно как и др портов [хАМР](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache%E2%80%93MySQL%E2%80%93PHP_packages) на [винде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP)). Остальное  производные.

Comment: Денвер ещё жив?)) Используйте что-нить другое, на Windows вроде бы OpenServer есть.

Answer (score 0):

используйте импорт через командную строку

```
mysql -u "root" -P "3306" -h "127.0.0.1" -B "test_db" < D:\1.sql
```